# Netbeans: Install/Activate/Uninstall/Deactivate plugins buttons disabled

Tags: plugins, netbeans

I recently installed Netbeans 6.9 on a new computer.  I went to install the NB Android plugin, which I have on another computer, but I found most of the functionality of the plugins window disabled.  The install, uninstall, activate, and deactivate buttons are grayed out.  I have included images at the bottom.  This hasn't happened to me before, and searching Google hasn't turned up anything useful.

I thought it might have been a permission problem so I tried running Netbeans with gksudo but that didn't help.  I also thought it might have been something wonky with the Ubuntu Software Center install, so I uninstalled that one, and downloaded Netbeans from the main site and I installed it in my home directory, but it does the same thing.

I'm running Xubuntu 10.10 and Netbeans 6.9.1

[image: Available Plugins Tab]

[image: Installed Tab]

Comment: hello? are you looking at this?  if i was unclear in some way or it isn't working let me know....it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to right click and select the plugin

Comment: i don't mean to be trite, it threw me for a second also not having a checkbox or highlighting working for install.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in NetBeans 6.9.1, where I could right click on any individual plugin, but Activate, Deactivate, and Uninstall were all greyed out.

I realized, quite by accident, that it is possible to select individual packages for uninstallation by using the space bar to mark a package as selected.